# how to write Authentication method in REST web service with json object in java?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am beginner in rest web service, from GUI I am receiving user details as the json object {"username":" abs","password":"abs"}.
To authenticate user, I need to process this object, here is the code below I am using it but still response is error code on GUI.
@Path("/user")

```
public class UserAuth 
{

@POST
@Path("/valid") 
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
public Response isValid(JSONObject userDetails )
    {
        String userId = (String) userDetails.get("username");
        String password = (String) userDetails.get("password");

    try 
    {
        System.out.println("User id : " + userId + "\t password : " + password);
        DBConnection userList = new DBConnection();
        userList.isUserValid(userId, password);
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UserAuth.class");
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("This is my first log4j's statement");

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
}//end of isValid Method.

}//end of UserAuth Class.
```

What am I missing ? Also I have all the jar in my lib.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 415 (Unsupported Media Type).. this what I can see on browser console.

Comment: Probably your request is not seen as an "application/json". Try to add a HTTP Header "Content-Type:application/json" in your POST request,

Comment: It worked finally but changing the code posted here but I had to change in code in my js file to get data exactly in a format it was needed.
Here is the below format change i did..

 data:'{"username":"'+$('#username').val()+'","password":"'+$('#password').val()+'"}',